# 2D array in a struct - is is possible?

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, malloc, structure

I am attempting to make a struct with a 2D array in it to store strings. But I keep getting a double free error when I execute the program

struct:

```
    struct room{
        int x;
        int y;
        char ** floor;
};
```

Here is my malloc:

```
struct room * newRoom = malloc(sizeof(struct room));
newRoom->floor = malloc(sizeof(char *) * height);
if(newRoom->floor == NULL || newRoom == NULL)
{
    printf("Room allocation failed \n");
}
for(i=0; i<width ;i++)
{
    newRoom->floor[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (width + 1));
    if(newRoom->floor[i] == NULL)
    {
        printf("Room string allocation failed \n");
    }
}
```

and my free, which is what seems to be causing the error:

```
for(i=0; i<size ;i++)
{
    free(toBeFreed->floor[i]);
}
free(toBeFreed->floor);
free(toBeFreed);
```

I don't really do much with the array other than fill it with characters (using for loops) and call mvprintw() so I don't *think* the problem is in between. What am I doing incorrectly?

Edit: so I should've clarified but width == height == size, the variables are in different files, so they do differ a little

EDIT2: apparently height != width, and I can't even keep my own variable name straight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(i=0; i<width ;i++)
```

should be

```
for(i=0; i<height;i++)
```

right?

and

```
for(i=0; i<size ;i++)
{
    free(toBeFreed->floor[i]);
}
```

should be

```
for(i=0; i<height;i++)
{
    free(toBeFreed->floor[i]);
}
```

Also

```
malloc(sizeof(char) * (width + 2));
```

Where does the +2 come from?

Other than that it seems rather ok, can you supply code how you want to use it?

Comment: the +2 was because I originally thought I was having trouble with a '\0' character, I changed this back to +1 thanks, also height=size=width, they were snippets from different files so I forgot to change them when copy/pasting

Comment: @Snipe07 But it still doesnt work? If so probably you are calling the routine who does the freeing twice? Have you tried to set a break point on the free routine and steep it thro to see what the values are?

Comment: nevermind height != width lol I need to use better variable names! thank you!

Answer (score 3):

When allocating you use:

```
for(i=0; i<width ; i++)
```

When freeing, you use:

```
for(i=0; i<size ;i++)
```

If width != size, you're going to have issues.